# Creating a new list Item from a string

Tags: c#, string, list, text

I have a program with a combo box, a list for that box and a string.

The string is created from user input via a text box and is saved each time the program closes. So if I type "Input Text" then close and open the program the combo box will have a list containing 1 string which displays "Input Text"

The issue is I want to keep adding to the list with new information but at the moment its just constantly overriding what I put in last time.

How do I add to my list with a new item each time the string is different?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load Settings
    saveLocationTextBox.Text = MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"].ToString();

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(saveLocationTextBox.Text);

    comboBox.DataSource = list;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Save User Input
    MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"] = saveLocationTextBox.Text;
    MySettings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Try putting the list in a separate file

Comment: You need to save the existing list of strings assigned to the combobox as data source, and in `Form1_Load` you should add the new string to that saved list of strings rather than creating a new list and adding it into that list. Because each time you are creating a new list from scratch and you only add the new string into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving only the selected item text in your settings, not all the items in the combo box.

I suggest to get all the items in the combo first and put them in a comma delimited string.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Save User Input
    string[] itemsToStore = new string[comboBox.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        itemsToStore[i] = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.Items[i]); 
    }

    MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"] = saveLocationTextBox.Text;
    MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationItems"] = string.Join(",", itemsToStore);
    MySettings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load Settings
    saveLocationTextBox.Text = MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"].ToString();

    string listItems = MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationItems"].ToString();

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.AddRange(listItems.Split(','));

    comboBox.DataSource = list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of overriding the text in the file do:

```
var items = comboBox.Items.Select(item => comboBox.GetItemText(item)).ToList();
items.Add(saveLocationTextBox.Text);

MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"] = string.Join(";", items);
```

And then when reading it:

```
var text = MySettings.Default["SaveSaveLocationText"].ToString();
comboBox.DataSource = text.Split(';').ToList();
```